# Проблема с php,и базой данных

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

При переходе по ссылке Выдаёт ошибку
[http://домен/index.php](http://%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD/index.php) 
**[image: текст, выделенный жирным шрифтом]**

в error log выдаёт ошибку,что якобы что то с php кодом не так.

вот код

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?php
include 'globals.php'

if($_POST['login'] == null || $_POST['password'] == null || $_POST['hwid'] ==  null)
    die();

$controller = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_LOGIN,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);

$u_login = $_POST['login'];
$u_password = $_POST['password'];
$u_hwid = $_POST['hwid'];

$rsp = $controller->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='$u_login' AND password='$u_password'");
if(@rsp->num_rows == 0)
    die("2");

$u_data = $rsp->fetch_assoc();
$id = $u_data['id'];
$db_hwid = $u_data['hwid'];

if($db_hwid == null){
    $controller->query("UPDATE users SET hwid='WHERE' id='$id'");
    die("3");
}

if($db_hwid != $u_hwid)
    die("4");

die("1");
?>
```

globals.php

```
<?php
define("DB_HOST","localhost");
define("DB_LOGIN","данные");
define("DB_PASSWORD","данныеr");
define("DB_NAME","данные");
?>
```

Comment: В ошибках всё понятно написано, скорее всего где-то запятую или точку с запятой не поставили или лишнюю поставили.

Comment: Приложите лог ошибки нормально(**текстом**).
Приложите тот код который у вас залит на сайт символ в символ(99% что первая строка не совпадает с той что вы привели). Приложите файл конфигурации php или его сумарный вариант в виде phpinfo();

Answer (score 0):

Первая ошибка говорит нам о том что у вас первая строка в файле не совпадет с тем что вы привели нам в качестве кода в частности в ней есть еще символы(возможно непечатаемые).
Вторая ошибка говорит что вы не поставили точку с запятой после include.

Замените первые две строки на

```
<?php
  include 'globals.php';
```

Альтернативный вариант, не уверен что такая экзотика существует, но всеже приведу его:

```
<?
  include 'globals.php';
```